# SSIS SQL timeout error handler

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are experiencing intermittent infrastrucutre issues that will sometimes cause our SSIS job to fail with a SQL timeout. Generally, re-running them works. However I've tried setting up error handlers to catch this and send an email. I have not been able to get this to work. Some of the jobs generate emails themselves, and those work, so I think I rule out mail server issues.

Is there something about this type of error/failure that won't fire the event handler?

Oh and yes we have increased the timeout value, it's just that when this occurs there is nothing that will allow the job to complete.

> OnError,...,-1073450910,0x,System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

Comment: Your question is incomplete because you are saying only what is the problem you want to solve but what cause this so that you are using event handler. Can you explain what are you doing in Control Flow?

Comment: It seems to be strictly server performance related. Most times the job runs fine, it is a standard SQL query with a UNION